# Average of elements in a subarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, average

I have an array like `a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. I want to split this array into 3 chunks of any size.

When I split this into 3 chunks, I get 3 subarrays: `[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7])]`.

My goal is to get an array with the average of the elements in a subarray: `[2, 4.5, 6.5]`, since `(1+2+3)/3=2` (first element), `(4+5)/2=4.5` (second element), and so on.

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a_split=np.array_split(a, 3)
a_split_avg=np.mean(a_split, axis=1)
```

I am getting the following error: `tuple index out of range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because `np.array_split` returns a python list of numpy array, not a multidimentional numpy array, so `axis` wouldn't work with it. Replace the last line with this:

```
a_split_avg = [np.mean(arr) for arr in a_split]
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vectorized solution that avoids the splitting step to gain performance and directly gets the grouped summations and hence averages -

```
def average_groups(a, N): # N is number of groups and a is input array
    n = len(a)
    m = n//N
    w = np.full(N,m)
    w[:n-m*N] += 1
    sums = np.add.reduceat(a, np.r_[0,w.cumsum()[:-1]])
    return np.true_divide(sums,w)
```

Sample run -

```
In [357]: a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [358]: average_groups(a, N=3)
Out[358]: array([2. , 4.5, 6.5])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.vectorize` in your calculation to apply the `mean` function to each item in the list of arrays:

```
means = np.vectorize(np.mean)(a_split)
```

The result is a list with the mean for each sub-array you create.

Comment: You might want to add this from the doc on `np.vectorize` : `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`.

Comment: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [1224]: mean_arr = []
In [1225]: for i in a_split:
      ...:     mean_arr.append(np.mean(i))
      
In [1226]: 

In [1226]: mean_arr
Out[1226]: [2.0, 4.5, 6.5]
```

OR use `List Comprehensions`:

```
In [6]: mean_arr = [np.mean(i) for i in a_split]

In [7]: mean_arr
Out[7]: [2.0, 4.5, 6.5]
```

Comment: I appreciate it.

Comment: Why not at least a loop comprehension...

Comment: @Sergo055 I've edited to use a list comprehension. Thanks for the suggestion.