# Taking mean of numpy arrays of different lengths within another numpy array without using for loop

Tags: python, vectorization, mean, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a 2d array that contains other arrays but the arrays are of different sizes. I want to find the mean of each individual array that is contained in that 2d array without using a loop.

I want to take the mean of array_combined in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array2=np.array([1,2,3])
array3=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
list_combined = [array1,array2,array3]
array_combined = np.array(list_combined)
```

Comment: How can a 2D array contain arrays of different sizes?

Comment: This array in the code above is an example of an array that contains other arrays of different sizes.@navneethc

Comment: i already tried .mean(axis=1) and .mean(axis=0) by taking transpose of array_combined but they didnt work.@AminS

Comment: No, you have 3 separate 1D arrays, then you put them in a list -- that's two different data structures. The mechanics of a 2D array is different: each of its rows must have equal length. If you don't want to go through a for loop, you could just define your combined array as `array_combined = np.array([array1.mean(), array2.mean(), array3.mean()])`.

Comment: Im supposed to find the mean of the arrays inside the arrays i cannot change array_combined. @navneethc

Comment: array_combined .mean(axis=1) this should work otherwise i don't know what are u trying to achieve.

Comment: @AminS a list does not have a `mean()` method.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZain can you add to your post the `array_combined` you have or a simplified example?

Comment: i have to take the mean of array combined not list combined @AminS. I just used list combined as  a way to create array combined.

Comment: not list. actually numyp object ( array ) @navneethc

Comment: @AminS, yeah your original post contained the list. :)

Comment: Basically i have already found the result using np.mean with for loop and appending it in a list or array but i want to do it without using for loop through numpy or array manipulation. The array combined i had is also like this .@navneethc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np
array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array2=np.array([1,2,3])
array3=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
list_combined = [array1,array2,array3]
array_combined = np.array(list_combined)

mean_sub_arrays = np.vectorize(np.mean)(array_combined)
```

Ran it on Google Colab to verify and attached screenshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR8Zd.png)

Copied from solution provided by @vielkind on this link:
[Average of elements in a subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178018/average-of-elements-in-a-subarray)

Answer (score 0):

If lengths are equal.

```
import numpy as np
list_combined=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])

print(list_combined.mean(axis=1))
#
''' 
array([3., 3., 3.])
'''
#
#
```

if not

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
list_combined=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,numpy.NAN,numpy.NAN],[1,2,3,4,5]])

print(np.nanmean(list_combined,axis=1))
#
''' 
[3. 2. 3.]
'''
#
#
```

Comment: The problem here is, the OP's arrays are of unequal lengths.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. I wanted to ask about the unequal length mean without using loops.@Amin S

Comment: This is still not the the solution np.nan are added as elements to the second array. I just want to find the mean of array_combined as it is written above in my question. @AminS

Comment: u cannot use array_combined = np.array(list_combined) if lengths are not equal. @SyedMuhammadZain edit the question then ask precisely or let me know how did u achieve that because as u know should be equal as an array.

Comment: This array_combined is actually output from a different code and it is achieved after splitting an array.@AminS

Comment: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part. "" Your code gives this error. i don't know more. @SyedMuhammadZain

Comment: I am not getting any error I am using jupyter notebook. @AminS

Comment: have  u run your code fully once in jupyter ?  can u print it ? weird actually. that was the whole point in my approach.